# AWK, How to count uniq http code

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file with http code eg. 200, 400, 505... there are a lot of. Can I have list unique data and count  the number of individual code using awk?

Comment: What does the file look like? Are there any other numbers in it?

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat file
200
400
200
200
404
500
404
404
500
500
500

$ awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' file
200 3
400 1
500 4
404 3
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't even need to use AWK for this task:

```
$ cat tmp 
200
400
200
200
404
500
404
404
500
500
500
chuchao@chuchao:~/tmp/
$ sort tmp | uniq -c
      3 200
      1 400
      3 404
      4 500
```

Comment: I know, but a must make this task using only awk.